# How can i fix the damaged area on varnished hardwood floor?

Tags: hardwood-floor

The area was damaged when a bottle of black mould killer tripped over. I hadn't realised till it was too late. Any recommendations on how to fix it without redoing the floors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are we supposed to guess what kind of damage you are talking about?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Home Improvement. Please provide more information such as the brand of mold killer and your type of floor. A picture would be very helpful

Comment: A question similar to this was asked a week or so ago - the answers you will find useful.